# I'm making an email finder and I keep running through an error I can't fix. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: python

## This function checks if any character mystr[x] matches "@"

```
 def findAtSymbol(mystr):
        pos = 0
        for x in range(0, len(mystr)):
            if mystr[x] == "@":
                pos = x + 1
                print("The character @ is present at", pos ,"position")
                break
            if pos == 0:
                print("No such character available in string")
    
    a = input("Give a string: ")
    y = findAtSymbol(a)
    print(y)
```

## This function checks if mystr[x] matches mychar

```
    def find(mystr, mychar, index):
        pos = 0
        for x in range(0, len(mystr)):
            if mystr[x] == mychar:
                pos = x + 1
                print("The string matches the character")
                break
            if pos == 0:
                print("The string does not match the character")

    a = input("Give a string: ")
    b = input("Give a character: ")
    y = find(a,b)
print(y)
```

## This is the error it gives me

```
TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your call `find(a, b)` you have only passed two of three required parameters.